# LINQ Query to select data and convert into specific json format

Tags: c#, json, linq, model-view-controller

Please help to get the solution for the problem.

i have the data from sql server like

```
Name   ColumnName  Value
------------------------------------------------
Login      FirstName         ABC
Login      LastName         XYX
```

and my requirement is to get the data like in json

`{
    Name: "Login",
    Data: [
        FirstName: "ABC",
        LastName: "XYZ"
    ]
}`

and i have written query but i didnt get exact output

This is the query looks like i am close please help me to get the result like above json

```
`var data = myDbEntities.GetSectionData(Id)
            .GroupBy(section=> new { section.Name })
            .OrderBy(section => section.Key.Section)
            .Select(section => new
            {
                Section = section.Key.Section,
                Data = section.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                (
                    c.ColumnName,
                    c.Value
                ))
            }).ToDictionary(c => c.Section);
        return data;`
```

Comment: The json you want to output(your example) isn't valid JSON, I assume the array should be an object instead?

Comment: I get what you're asking to do, but the *"why?"* factor is too strong.  You really have a table with that data in it - a field called Name with the values "Login"?  Also, I think the simplest solution would be to output the data in a simple list of objects and then map the JSON output wherever it's being used.  I'm guessing it'll be used by Javascript somewhere, which means that it almost doesn't matter what format it is when you return it, since Javascript doesn't care and makes it *very* easy to map arrays into objects, even with dynamic field names.

Answer (score 2):

You could supply more data but I think the part you supplied is enough to deduct what you want. As I understand your source table has columns like (Id, Name, ColumnName and Value). You want to have your data as JSON for a given ID, using "columnname" values as json keynames. Your sample json, although is invalid, close to final output (code uses Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet):

```
 var data = myDbEntities
    .Where(jt => jt.Id==1) 
    // probably your GetSectionData(id) is doing the same thing

    .GroupBy(jt => jt.Name)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(jt => new {
        Name = jt.Key,
        Data = jt.ToDictionary(j => j.ColumnName, j => j.Value)
    });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

EDIT: Sample output:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Login",
    "Data": {
      "FirstName": "ABC",
      "LastName": "XYZ"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Login1",
    "Data": {
      "Prop 1": "ABCD",
      "Prop 2": "ABCDE",
      "Prop 3": "Alfa"
    }
  }
]
```